# Calculation on text fields against each other using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I am trying to calculate results on textfields. I have two textfields and when someone enter value like `3 or 4` on first textfield it generate result on second textfield.I am also trying that if someone try to enter values on second one then it will show result on first one.It works fine for first condition but not for second.My code is below .My second textfield not allowing me to change value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('.product-custom-option').on('keyup', function() {
        var total = jQuery('.product-custom-option').val();
       var perunit = 3;     
       var newprice = total/perunit;
       jQuery('#no_packs').val(Math.ceil(newprice));

    });
});
jQuery(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery('#no_packs').on('keyup', function() {
        var total = jQuery('#no_packs').val();
       var perunit = 3;      
       var newprice = total * perunit;
       jQuery('.product-custom-option').val(newprice);
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<dl class="last">          
<dt>
</dt><dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Square meters required</label>
    </dt>
<dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" id="options_134_text" class="input-text required-entry  product-custom-option" name="options[134]" value="">
            </div>
</dd>
        </dl>
<div class="">
<label class="required">Number of Packs</label>
<div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="no_packs" class="input-text product-custom-option" name="qty" value="">
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post some `html` too.. Will be cool if you add a demo snippet..

Comment: what is `opConfig.reloadPrice()`?

Comment: try using parseInt (or parseFloat if you need floats ) on the value you got from the input

Comment: @BenG opConfig.reloadPrice() is for price change.this have no effect on current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are defining same class on both the input fields so when you enter value on second input both functions works because second input field have a same class.

Add different class in first field and then use the same class in function

```js
    jQuery(function(jQuery) {
      jQuery('.first').on('keyup', function() {
        var total = jQuery('.product-custom-option').val();
        var perunit = 3;
        var newprice = total / perunit;
        jQuery('#no_packs').val(Math.ceil(newprice));

      });
    });
    jQuery(function(jQuery) {
      jQuery('#no_packs').on('keyup', function() {
        var total = jQuery('#no_packs').val();
        var perunit = 3;
        var newprice = total * perunit;
        jQuery('.first').val(newprice);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="last">
  <dt>
</dt><dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Square meters required</label>
    </dt>
  <dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" id="options_134_text" class="input-text required-entry product-custom-option first" name="options[134]" value="">
    </div>
  </dd>
</dl>
<div class="">
  <label class="required">Number of Packs</label>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" id="no_packs" class="input-text product-custom-option" name="qty" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

> Well i am ignoring `onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"` as may be you are using it in some way but it's showing console errors check about it

Comment: Thanks but if you check your demo if you enter some values on first and then change on second it will not allow you.This is main issue

Comment: @MahmoodRehman great catch..well that the same thing i have use class in second function you need to mention id there also

Comment: Yes its working fine now but could we use class for the first one ? as i have to use class instead of id.and this this class is unique on this page so will not effect other things

Comment: you can use class as well but you cant use same class in both the fields...if you need to write different functions for both fields...do one thins just add a different class in first field and use class in function..check updated answer